# Git reset does not update the changes on the remote server

Tags: git, github, deployment, github-actions

I am currently learning with GitHub Actions. My goal is to build a deplyoment pipeline for a small private web project (website). And independently of that I noticed something I don't understand.

Best I explain it with an example. But first my setup:

- remote repository "Project_X" is on GitHub
- GH Action starts a SSH connection to the remote server on every push to initialize a `git pull` there.
- done!

This works fine so far.

Now I tested what would happen if my last push contains an error and I want to undo it. So that the page continues to run and I can do the BugFix.
So I entered local: `git reset --hard hash_from_prev_commit`.
Locally, the commit was reset. With `git push -f` the remote repository was also updated. But on the remote server it was not reset. GitHub Action output:

```
out: /www/htdocs/w019db06
out: On branch master
out: Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
out: nothing to commit, working directory clean
err: From github.com:Project-X/git-workflow-test
err: + ffd263c...e5a9ec8 master -> origin/master (forced update)
out: Already up-to-date.
==============================================
✅ Successfully executed commands to all host.
```

Why is this and what do I have to do so that the change takes effect on the remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

You need to get the third repository to run `git fetch` followed by `git reset --hard`, as in:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

if you're willing to hard-code the name `master` here.

## Long

Let me summarize here by saying that there are *three* repositories.  Let's give them names: Alfred, Barbara, and Catwoman.  Repository A (Alfred) is on your laptop.  Repository B (Barbara) is on GitHub.  Repository C is on your server, whatever that may be.

For simplicity, actions taken *on* A, by some Git process run because you ran some `git whatever` command on your laptop, are "Git A"; those on B (on GitHub) are "Git B", and those that occur on C are "Git C".  This should help keep straight what happens on each machine, in each repository.

This line, plus the next one that I won't quote yet:

> ```
> + ffd263c...e5a9ec8 master -> origin/master (forced update)
> ```

is printed by Git C, because Git C is running `git pull`.  But `git pull` means: *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.

#### Background (a bit long, skim if you like)

Now, before we proceed, we need to make a few more notes:

1. Git is all about *commits*.  It's not about branch names or files: the branch names help some Git repository *find* commits, and the commits *contain* files, but we're really concerned with the *commits*.
2. Commits are *shared:* if repositories A, B, and C are cross-connected to each other, they eventually all wind up with the *same* commits.
3. Commits are numbered, with big ugly hash IDs.  Normally I like to use single uppercase letters to stand in for these, and I can do that here as long as I start deeper in the alphabet (A, B, and C are the repositories on the various machines, so I want to avoid those letters).
4. Each commit *contains*, as part of its metadata, the raw hash ID of some *previous* commit or commits.  Most commits have just one previous hash ID, which forms the commits into backwards-looking chains:

   ```
   ... <-F <-G <-H
   ```

   where `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *latest* commit in the chain.  Commit `H`, *being* the latest, is the *end* of the chain: there are no more commits after this point.
5. As noted in item 1, a Git repository will use *branch names* to help it *find* commits.  But the branch names *are not shared:* each Git repository has *its own* branch names.

Now, being a bit lazy, I tend to draw the commits like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here we see how the current branch name—in this case `master`—points to the *last* commit in the chain.  The process of making a *new* commit is done, in Git, by checking out some commit (`H`), using some branch name (`master`), which makes that branch the *current branch* and that particular commit the *current commit*.  Then we act on the files in our working tree, use `git add` to "stage" them, and run `git commit`, and Git builds a *new* commit `I`, that points back to the current commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

As the last step of `git commit`, Git writes `I`'s actual hash ID—some big ugly hexadecimal number—into the name `master`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now the chain of commits ends not at `H` but at `I`.

When we use `git push` or `git fetch`, our Git calls up some other Git and either sends them our new commits (`git push`) or gets any new commits from them (`git fetch`).  This is how the commits get shared.  But after that, things get a little weirder: if we're using `git fetch`, our Git updates, not a *branch* name, but rather a *remote-tracking* name.  For instance, if we got a new commit `J` from *their* Git, we would now have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
               \
                J   <-- origin/master
```

We can now *add* commit `J` to *our* branch (our `master`, which is independent of *their* `master`) using various Git operations, to get:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

For various reasons, `git push` is different: after we send our new commit to some other repository, we ask them (politely) if they will please, if it's OK, set *their* branch name to some particular commit.  For instance, if they have only commits up through `H`, we can send them commit `I`, or commits `I-J`, that *add on* to their `H` like this, and then ask them to set their `master`.

#### The problem

Let's review what kicks all this off.  You, on your laptop—on Git A—are going to run:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

or equivalent.  This moves *your* branch name `master` back one commit.  But we don't get there all at once.

Let's say you started with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You then added commit `I` in *your* repository `A`:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

You then ran `git push origin master`.  That sent new commit `I` to repo B, and then asked them to make their `master` point to `I`, which they did:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You then had repo B tickle repo C, which ran `git pull origin master` or just `git pull` (both do the same thing).  Repo C called up repo B and got what to repo C was new: commit `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- origin/master
```

The *second* command that your `git pull` ran on C was `git merge`.  This discovered that there was no need for a true merge, so it just *added commit `I`* to its `master`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

So now, repos A and C match (down to both having an `origin/master` name pointing to commit `I`, as copied from repo B and renamed).  Repo B has its `master` pointing to commit `I`.

**And now we reset commit `I` away on repo A.**  (Whew, finally.)  Let's draw that:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- origin/master
```

Repo A still remembers that repo B is using commit `I` as repo B's `master`.  That's true!

You might now run `git push origin master` from `A` and get an error about it not being a fast-forward:

```
! rejected ... (non-fast-forward)
```

That's because your Git talked with their Git, found that you had no commits to send, and ended with a polite request that they set their `master` to point to `H`.  That's a polite request that they *forget* commit `I`, and they say *no*.

So you resort to `git push -f` or equivalent.  This changes the final step of `git push` from a polite request, *please set your `master` to point to `H`*, to a forceful command: *Set your `master` to point to `H`!*  If they obey, this happens in repo B:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I   ???
```

Note that repo B *has no name* for commit `I` any more.  You can still access it by raw hash ID (GitHub allow you to do this with their APIs and web interface), but you have to know the hash ID.

Now, this `git push` onto GitHub triggers Repo A to do a `git pull`, which—again—is just `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, in this case, `git merge`.  Repo C currently has this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

They run `git fetch origin` and see that, in repo B (on GitHub), `master` selects commit `H`.  This means that they can make their `origin/master` point to commit `H`, but only by doing a *forced* update: it's a "non-fast-forward", in Git jargon.

So, they do that.  Now they have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

That is, Repo C *still has commit `I`*.  It's right there at the end of their `master`.

Their Git now runs its *second* step for `git pull`, which is to run `git merge origin/master` (more or less—it actually works off the raw hash ID at this point, internally).  That tells them to add commit `H` into their chain that ends at commit `I`.  Commit `H` is *already in this chain*, so they print:

> ```
> Already up-to-date.
> ```

and then do nothing.

#### What's wrong is now obvious (well, as clear as things get in Git)

The problem here is that `git merge`—the default second command of `git pull`—is just *wrong*.  You don't want to *merge* new commits in, on repo C.  You want to *switch to the latest commit on some branch on repo B*.  That's recorded in `origin/master`, in the case of repo B's `master`.

The `git pull` command can be told to run a different second command: instead of `git merge`, you can have it use `git rebase`.  But that's equally wrong, or maybe even "wronger" (if that's a thing).  You don't want either of those.

#### Git isn't a deployment tool

The ultimate problem here is that you're treating Git as a deployment tool, and it just isn't one.  It *can* be *used as* one, much as a screwdriver can be used as a chisel, or a drill press can be used to tighten screws.  It's just an abuse of the tool, to some extent.  You need to be sure you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks @torek for your really good answer. I accept your answer immediately. Was just happy to use deployment with the help of Git for this :-) Looks like I'll have to look into deployment tools / strategies in more depth after all.

Comment: If you could get Git B to recognise that Git A had done a reset. Then you could put that logic into the GitHub action and have it do `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master` instead of `git pull`. But I don't know how that would work! @torek Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't quite do that. You *can* set up fetch refspecs so that your branch names get overwritten, but to make that work, you need a bare repository, which means no working tree, which means no (direct) deployment. People who use (abuse?) Git as a deployment tool do tend to set up a bare repo and then use `git checkout` from there, but there are issues with this method as well.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I notice you don't like the approach of using Git as a deployment tool ;-) Can you please recommend an alternative? After your answer, I thought about creating a new folder for each commit on the remote server and uploading the data to it with scp. So without git at all on the remote Server.

Comment: I have never found anything I *like* as a deployment tool. There must be some half decent ones out there though...

Comment: Well, I'll have a look! Thanks again for your time.